# Upper bound on the magnitude of $e^{\sin z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I want to upper bound the magnitude of $|e^{\sin(z)}|$ over the line from $z =0 $ to $z = i$. Since $\sin(x + iy) = \sin(iy)$ as $x = 0$ throughout the line,  I've proceeded as follows:

$$|e^{\sin(iy)}| = e^{\Re(\sin(iy))} = e^{\Re(\frac{e^{-y} - e^{y}}{2i})} \leq e^{\Re(e^{-y} - e^{y})} = e^{e^{-y} - e^{y}}.$$

Graphing the function $e^{-y} - e^{y}$ reveals that its maximum is $0$, so would the upper bound of this magnitude be $e^{0} = 1$?

Comment: I assume you're doing a contour integral. Care to share? :)

Comment: @FShrike I just want to use ML bound on the integral $\int_{\gamma} e^{sin z} dz$ where $\gamma$ is the line from $z =0 $ to $z= i$.

Comment: For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\left|e^{\sin(ix)}\right|=\left|e^{i\sinh(x)}\right|=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $y \in \Bbb R$ is
$$
 \sin(iy) = \frac{e^{-y}-e^y}{2i}
$$
purely imaginary, and therefore $|e^{\sin(iy)}| = 1$.

So your result is correct, but the argument is wrong.
The estimate
$$
\Re(\frac{e^{-y} - e^{y}}{2i}) \leq \Re(e^{-y} - e^{y})
$$
does not hold  for $0 < y \le 1$: the left-hand side zero, whereas the right-hand side is negative.

Answer (score 2):

More in general, we have that

$$\sin(z)=\sin (x+iy)=\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x \sinh y$$

then

$$e^{\sin(z)}=e^{\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x \sinh y}=e^{\sin x\cosh y}e^{i\cos x \sinh y}$$

therefore since $\forall \theta \;|e^{i\theta}|=1$ we have

$$|e^{\sin(z)}|=e^{\sin x\cosh y}$$

and for $x=0$, that is $z=iy$, we obtain $|e^{\sin(z)}|=e^0=1$.